# Remove border from first TD in table

Tags: html, css

My current table looks like this:

[image: Current Table]

I want to remove the border from the first two TD's/TH's so that it looks like this:

[image: What I want from Table]

(The second image was modified in Paint to show what I'd like to achieve)

The only styling I'm currently using is:

```
table 
{ 
    border-collapse:collapse; 
}
```

Because without it, my Table looks really bad like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to achieve what I want? I've looked around, and tried applying different code snippets here and there but nothing seems to give me what I want. Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**

I didn't think to add my Table Markup because I was sure the problem wasn't coming from there, I literately only had one line of CSS and nothing else, but it was because of the `<table border="1">` which made it so that none of my CSS snippets I tried worked.

Comment: Which markup are you using for the table?

Comment: `empty-cells: hide;` ?

Comment: try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mFQ6q/)

Comment: Since you say that you only have one style rule and yet there are borders, you must have a `border` attribute in the `table` tag and you must be using `th` markup for the first row. Please clarify this in the question itself by including the relevant HTML markup.

Comment: I just noticed my stupid mistake. I forgot I still had the <table border='1'> which was preventing my other styling from working. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a fiddle so I'll post it anyway even if you already got working answers.

http://jsfiddle.net/amenadiel/rV7Yw/

```
.mytable tr:first-child td:nth-child(1), 
.mytable tr:first-child td:nth-child(2) {
    border:1px transparent;    
}
```

Comment: The fiddle you made helped me notice I was still using <table border='1'>. After removing it, I was able to get it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the border of the two th with this css :

```
table tr:first th:nth(1), table tr:first th:nth(2) {
    border: none;
}
```

Note that it may not work on some old Internet Explorer versions.
Note too that you may replace `th` by `td`, depending of your html structure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
table  tr:first-child > th:first-child, table  tr:first-child > th:first-child + th{ 
    border:none; 
}
```

If you are not sure whether you are using `th` then also keep the below css:

```
table  tr:first-child > td:first-child, table  tr:first-child > td:first-child + td,
table  tr:first-child > th:first-child, table  tr:first-child > th:first-child + th {
     border: none;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/E2kzW/2/)

Comment: This is not sufficient if the markup has `<table border>`, as it must have if the borders have not been set in CSS, as the case seems to be.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela yeah not sure though whether OP is having border attribute. Anyway, I did this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/E2kzW/3/) which seems to cover the case which you mentioned above.